# How to convert the following encrypted code into js?

Tags: javascript, java, encryption

**I don't know how to use getByte() in js,and use CryptoJS to encrypted.**

I decompile a program and get a program for the encryption algorithm. I have to convert it to js. I don't know how to handle this function in js because of the existence of getByted() in java.

The password that generates desede must use getByte(), which makes me very annoyed. If this password can be changed to the correct string, I think I can solve this problem.

```java
//function m2866a,a program for generating a password 
//function m2865a，a encrypted program.
public static String m2865a(byte[] bArr, byte[] bArr2) {
        try {
            if (bArr.length == 16) { // short key ? .. extend to 24 byte key
                byte[] tmpKey = new byte[24];
                System.arraycopy(bArr, 0, tmpKey, 0, 16);
                System.arraycopy(bArr, 0, tmpKey, 16, 8);
                bArr = tmpKey;
            }
            for (byte i : bArr) {
                System.out.print(i+",");
            }
            System.out.println();
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(bArr, "DESede");
            Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/NoPadding");
            instance.init(1, secretKeySpec);
            return m2864a(instance.doFinal(m2869b(bArr2)));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e3) {
            e3.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e4) {
            e4.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e5) {
            e5.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
public static byte[] m2866a(int i, int i2) {
        byte[] bArr = new byte[16];
        bArr[0] = (byte) (i2 & 255);
        bArr[1] = (byte) (i & 255);
        bArr[2] = (byte) ((i >> 8) & 255);
        bArr[3] = 0;
        for (int i3 = 4; i3 < 8; i3++) {
            bArr[i3] = (byte) (bArr[i3 - 4] ^ -1);
        }
        for (int i4 = 8; i4 < 12; i4++) {
            bArr[i4] = (byte) (bArr[i4 - 8] ^ bArr[(bArr.length - i4) - 1]);
        }
        bArr[12] = (byte) (bArr[8] ^ 161);
        bArr[13] = (byte) (bArr[9] ^ 27);
        bArr[14] = (byte) (bArr[10] ^ 193);
        bArr[15] = (byte) (bArr[11] ^ 29);
        return bArr;
    }
private static byte[] m2869b(byte[] bArr) {
        int length = 8 - (bArr.length % 8);
        byte[] bArr2 = new byte[(bArr.length + length)];
        System.arraycopy(bArr, 0, bArr2, 0, bArr.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            bArr2[bArr.length + i] = 0;
        }
        return bArr2;
    }
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String CustomerID = "15";
        String AgentID = "37";
        String AccNum = "22194";
        String CardID = "2615021229";
        String AccName = "中文";
        String PerCode = "12345678";
        String OrderNumb = "12414255";
        String RandomNum = "116685";
        byte[] temp = C0646f.m2866a(Integer.parseInt(CustomerID), Integer.parseInt(AgentID));
        String a = C0646f.m2865a(
                C0646f.m2866a(Integer.parseInt(CustomerID), Integer.parseInt(AgentID)),
                ("1,1," + AgentID + "," + CustomerID + "," + AccNum + "," + CardID + "," + AccName + "," + PerCode + ","
                        + OrderNumb + "," + RandomNum).getBytes("GB2312")
        );
        System.out.println(a);
    }
```

Comment: by rewriting it. what? you were planning on just tossing code in a converter tool and automatically assuming the result to be correct?

Comment: Yes, I want to use js to achieve the same function as this java encryption code, as long as you get married

Comment: "as long as I get married" ????

Comment: emmm,Forgive me for junk English, just get the same result.

Comment: You are telling us what you are expecting, but your code makes no attempt to solve it. StackOverflow is not a free code writing service, so you need to attempt the task before you can have an issue with it requiring help. It may just be a simple case of use. More info at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask